# ¿Como puedo enviar el id de un dato a un modal?

Tags: php, jquery

Este es el documento del cual enviare el `id`

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax/paid/ajax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#btnPaid").click();
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
      $fact = FacturaData::getByTipoPago();
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php include("modals/rePaid.php"); ?>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Abonos</h1>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="prods" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <p><b>Buscar </b></p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" name="product" id="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar producto" class="form-control" autofocus>
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>Buscar</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-12">

      <?php if ($fact): ?>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="process" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>No.</th>
                  <th>Cliente</th>
                  <th>Vendedor</th>
                  <th>Fecha</th>
                  <th>Tipo De Documento</th>
                  <th>Total</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php foreach ($fact as $fa): ?>

                    <?php
                      $prodsx = FacturaData::getAllSellsByFactId($fa->id); #Productos vendidos en la factura
                      $servsx = FacturaData::getAllServicesByFactId($fa->id); #Servicios vendidos en la factura
                    ?>
*AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO QUE COJA EL ID Y ME LO ENVIE AL MODAL PARA LUEGO EN EL MODAL RECIBITLO CON GET*
                      <td style="width:40px;"><a id="btnPaid" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rePaid" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a></td>
                      <td><?php echo $fa->numerofactura; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $fa->getClient()->name." ".$fa->getClient()->lastname; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $fa->getUser()->name." ".$fa->getUser()->lastname; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $fa->fecha; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $fa->getComprobante()->nombre; ?></td>
                      <td>
                        <?php
                          $total=0;
                          foreach($prodsx as $p){
                            $prd = $p->getProduct();
                            $total += $p->cantidad * $prd->precioventa;
                          }
                          foreach ($servsx as $s) {
                            $srv = $s->getService();
                            $total += $s->cantidad * $srv->precio;
                          }
                          echo "<b>$ ".number_format($total,2,'.',',')."</b>";
                        ?>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <?php else: ?>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
              Vaya! No no se encontro ningun registro entre esas fechas.
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="servs" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p><b>Agregar servicio a la venta</b></p>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="resultado_srv">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice hace un par de días fue que al presionar el botón para abrir el modal, ese boton llama a una función, en la función tomas el valor del id, luego puedes cargar el id a un campo del modal mediante el .value. no sé si me expliqué muy bien, espero puedas entender. Estoy seguro que hay maneras más faciles de hacerlo, pero no las conozco. esto lo hice en javascript, no jquery.

Comment: gracias alexi gallegos

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es utilizar JQuery, cuando se active el evento que lanza el modal por ejemplo

$(document).ready{
 $("#campoID").value($("#id").value());
}

Ojo! ,tu puedes usar otro evento que lo lance esto es solo un ejemplo.!

Comment: solo una cosa en el evento el id es id="<?php echo $fa->id;?>"  como podria acomodarlo